Javascript getElementsByClassName Collection Count is decreasing automatically
I have a main div and inside this, I have 3 child div. What I want is to get all 3 child div on Body Onload function and change their appearance through class attribute.
My code is like this:
Html is:
<div class="w-100 vh-100" id="main-grid">
  <div class="border border-dark grid-section"></div>
  <div class="border border-dark grid-section">
    <div class="py-5 border border-danger d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div>
        <h2 class="text-primary" id="select-action">Select Form Action</h2>
        <div class="list-group">
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span> Sum of Natural Numbers</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Factorial Calculation</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Multiplication Table</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Count Digits in a Number</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Reverse a Number</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true" onclick="ChangeView(this)"> <span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Sum of Digits</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Print Even Numbers</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Print Odd Numbers</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Sum of Even Numbers</button>
          <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onclick="ChangeView(this)"><span class="me-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-right" style="color: #74C0FC;"></i></span>Sum of Odd Numbers</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border border-dark grid-section"></div>
</div>

Javascript is:
function setInitialView() {
  if (mainGrid) {
    var columns = mainGrid.getElementsByClassName("grid-section");
    if (columns != null && columns.length == 3) {
      try {
        columns[0].setAttribute("class", "d-none");
        columns[1].setAttribute("class", "d-block");
        columns[2].setAttribute("class", "d-none");
      } catch (e) {

      }
      let check = false;
    }
  }
}

Issue is:
In columns collection I get 3 child div as expected. But when I try to set class attribute of child it remove one child from columns list.
when columns[0].setattribute is called, columns.Length becomes 2
when columns[1].setattribute is called, columns.length becomes 1
and when last one is called columns[2] becomes null and thus throws exception.
I am not getting why collection is getting updated.
Please guide.

How is setInitialView() called? What is mainGrid?

Per the documentation, "This is a live HTMLCollection. Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed."

SetIntialView() is called on  and mainGrid is the parent grid ID containing 3 child div

Thank you. I got your point and it's working now. Actually I was not properly updating Class attribute due to which DOM was not picking it.  Thanks again
